# Is there problems with upgrading Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, stock, php-7.2

I received this error after upgrading Prestashop when I try to update the stock in Back Office for specific product.

There is Ajax Request which goes to fail when submit save button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question

The problems with updating stock appear on products with no principal category.

Even if you you choose more categories, you need one principal checked.